# Inverse Laplace Transform partial fraction $\frac {\frac{2S -1}{2}} {S^2-S+{\frac{5}{4}}} $

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

Can anybody help me with the answer of this question?

> Find the inverse Laplace transform of
>   $$\frac {\frac{2S -1}{2}} {S^2-S+{\frac{5}{4}}} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Rewrite it as
$$
\frac{\frac{2s-1}2}{s^2-s+\frac54}=\frac{(s-\frac12)}{(s-\frac12)^2+1}.
$$